# Which class in storm does instantiate the number of threads for each bolt and spout?

Tags: multithreading, apache-storm

I need to know how Storm manages number of parallel worker in each bolt. neither IrichBolt class nor IRichSpout Class implements Runnable class. I really need to know how storm manage multithreading?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its kinda too broad to discuss but here's something I could try to share. In very brief `Spouts` or `Bolts` in storm can be defined as an entity or component that actually process the data .  In storm terminology they are known as `tasks`(so you don't need its parent interface such as `IRichSpout` to implement something like Runnable ). Now the **Thread** which in responsible for carrying out *these tasks* are called `Executors`. From the doc

> in Storm’s terminology "*parallelism*" is specifically used to describe the so-called *parallelism hint*, which means the **initial number of executor (threads)** of a component (spout or bolt)

These executors (threads) are again spawned by the `worker process` . From the doc

> A worker process executes a subset of a topology. A worker process belongs to a specific topology and may run one or more executors for one or more components (spouts or bolts) of this topology

A machine in a storm cluster may `run single or multiple such worker process` for one or more topologies, and `each process can run executors for specific topologies` ( you can even change these executors during run time using the storm re-balancing mecanism). 
For internal communication with in these workers process Storm uses various message queues backed by [LMAX Disruptor](http://lmax-exchange.github.io/disruptor/) . They maintain their own threads like *receiver* thread &  *sender* thred for managing incoming and outgoing messages.
You can probably take look in [this](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Understanding-the-parallelism-of-a-Storm-topology) doc page for a better overview. And this [very nice article](http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2012/10/16/understanding-the-parallelism-of-a-storm-topology) explaining how it handles parallelism. This might help you digging further and share your findings :)